# Display array elements with next and prev button using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have an array which contains 10 objects, called `emailThreads`.

I am trying to display these objects with next and previous button but its not working as expected.

```
      <Controls>
        <Button onClick={previousEmail}>Previous Email</Button>
        <SubjectDetails>
          <Subject>SUBJECT</Subject>
          <SubjectTitle>{emailThreads[emailIndex].subject}</SubjectTitle>
          <SentAtDetails>Sent At {emailThreads[emailIndex].deliveredAt}</SentAtDetails>
        </SubjectDetails>
        <Button onClick={nextEmail}>Next Email</Button>
      </Controls>
```

this is code for `previousEmail` and `nextEmail`

```
  const [emailIndex, setEmailIndex] = useState(0);
  const previousEmail = () => {
    setEmailIndex((prevIndex) => {
      prevIndex !== 0 ? prevIndex - 1 : prevIndex;
    });
  };
  const nextEmail = () => {
    setEmailIndex((prevIndex) => {
      prevIndex !== emailThreads.length ? prevIndex + 1 : prevIndex;
    });
  };
```

when I click on the next email,

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subject')
```

any help would be wonderful, thank you

Comment: Why do you want `prevIndex` from where prevIndex is being passed?

Comment: @Junaid did you check our answers? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful because you are comparing with `length` and not `<= length - 2` (or `< length - 1`) so adding + 1 to the current index will - at some point - cause an exception.

Use something like this

```
const nextEmail = () => {
    setEmailIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex < emailThreads.length - 1 ? prevIndex + 1 : prevIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seem like you're not returning anything inside `setemailindex` callback so changing your code to

```
 setEmailIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex !== emailThreads.length ? prevIndex + 1 : prevIndex);
```

or

```
setEmailIndex((prevIndex) => {
    retrun  prevIndex !== emailThreads.length ? prevIndex + 1 : prevIndex;
    });
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this.

```
const previousEmail = () => {
    setEmailIndex(
      emailIndex !== 0 ? emailIndex - 1 : emailIndex;
    );
  };
  const nextEmail = () => {
    setEmailIndex(
      emailIndex !== emailThreads.length ? emailIndex + 1 : emailIndex;
    );
  };
```